# Even after declaring 'i' as global variable, it shows 'i' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas

```
   i = 0
    def func(x):
        global i
        sum1 = 0
        for ele in x:
            minus = ele - data['Mean'][i]
            sum1 += np.square(minus)
        i += 1
        return sum1

    data['Std'] = Top15_new.groupby('Continents').agg({"Population":func})
    return data
answer_eleven()


NameError: name 'i' is not defined
```

Comment: Can you fix the code example? I can't figure out your function... you have 2 return statements?

Comment: looks like it's not really global but `nonlocal`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since data is not provided, I made up the DataFrames and data.  I just indented your code as follows:

```
i = 0 
def func(x): 
   global i 
   sum1 = 0 
   for ele in x: 
      minus = ele - data['Mean'][i] 
      sum1 += np.square(minus) 
      i += 1   
   return sum1


data['Std'] = Top15_new.groupby('Continents').agg({"Population":func})

data
```

Here is the output of the above code with out error. Again the data is made up data

```
   Mean Std
0   2   NaN
1   3   NaN
2   4   1.0
3   5   5.0
4   6   NaN
```